# HTK HCompV: Input file is not in RIFF format

Tags: htk

I'm trying to use HTK and setting up a project accordingly. I managed to encode training data using HCopy successfully, but upon trying to execute:

```
HCompV -C config -f 0.01 -m -S codetr.scp -M hmm0 proto
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR [+6251] Input file is not in RIFF format
ERROR [+6213] OpenWaveInput: Get[format]HeaderInfo failed
ERROR [+6313] OpenAsChannel: OpenWaveInput failed
ERROR [+6316] OpenBuffer: OpenAsChannel failed
ERROR [+2050] LoadFile: Config parameters invalid
FATAL ERROR - Terminating program
```

For reference, I'm running this in an MSYS shell and the config is as follows:

```
# Coding parameters
SOURCEFORMAT = WAV # We read in .wav files
TARGETKIND = MFCC_0_D_A # Identifier for coefficients
TARGETRATE = 100000.0 # 10ms = frame periodicity
SAVECOMPRESSED = T
SAVEWITHCRC = T
WINDOWSIZE = 250000.0 # 25ms = time frame length
USEHAMMING = T # Use of Hamming function for windowing
PREEMCOEF = 0.97 # Pre-emphasis coefficient
NUMCHANS = 26 # Number of filterbank channels
CEPLIFTER = 22 # Length of cepstral filtering
NUMCEPS = 12 # Number of MFCC coefficients
ENORMALISE = F # Normalise intensity of data
```

the proto file is as follows:

```
~o <VecSize> 39 <MFCC_0_D_A>
~h "proto"
<BeginHMM>
  <NumStates> 5
  <State> 2
    <Mean> 39
      0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
    <Variance> 39
      1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 ...
  <State> 3
    <Mean> 39
      0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
    <Variance> 39
      1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 ...
  <State> 4
    <Mean> 39
      0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
    <Variance> 39
      1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 ...
  <TransP> 5
    0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    0.0 0.6 0.4 0.0 0.0
    0.0 0.0 0.6 0.4 0.0
    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.7 0.3
    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
<EndHMM>
```

and the codetr.scp file is as follows (all files are present):

```
samples/cough1.wav samples/cough1.mfc
samples/cough2.wav samples/cough2.mfc
samples/cough3.wav samples/cough3.mfc
samples/cough4.wav samples/cough4.mfc
samples/silence1.wav samples/silence1.mfc
samples/silence2.wav samples/silence2.mfc
samples/silence3.wav samples/silence3.mfc
samples/silence4.wav samples/silence4.mfc
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error.
I solved it in Windows by removing the SOURCEFORMAT = WAV

Also, you may have errors at some part regarding your proto file.
I'm pretty sure all doubles have to be on the same line, such as in your:
  5

0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ....should then continue on this line and not run onto another

Hope this helps!

Comment: you are a hero!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the input file format? On unix/linux, you can try file [filename]. Post the result of the test. A tool such as audacity can be used to convert to RIFF format.